# grid-like site header, creating pixel perfect arrangement

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin, padding

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CUJhJ/)

I'm trying to create a blog header that is best described as a grid format. Each item will have a specified position- top, bottom, left, right- with a border on each of it's sides. I've got the basic layout down, but finessing it into a pixel perfect grid is a bit beyond my reach. I've attached an image of what it should look like in the end. Below is the code.. what am I missing?

html-

```
<div id="blog-header">
        <span class="blog-logo"><img src="http://placehold.it/262x134" alt="logo" /></span><!-- end blog-logo -->
        <div class="mid">
            <p class="blurb">Hi, this is a brief bio.<br/>Ok that's it!</p><!-- end blurb -->
            <div class="blog-social">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" alt="facebook" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" alt="twitter" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" alt="instagram" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" alt="pinterest" /></a></li>
            </ul>
            </div><!-- end blog-social -->
        </div><!-- end mid -->
        <div class="right">
            <p class="blog-nav"><a href="index.php?page_id=7">PORTFOLIO<span style="padding: 0 5px 0 5px;">|</span></a><a href="index.php?page_id=26">BLOG<span style="padding: 0 5px 0 5px;">|</span></a><a href="index.php?page_id=5">ABOUT<span style="padding: 0 5px 0 5px;">|</span></a><a href="index.php?page_id=9">CONTACT</a></p>
            <div class="email">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x50">
            </div><!-- end email -->
        </div><!-- end right -->
    </div><!-- end blog-header -->
```

css-

```
#blog-header {
    height: 124px;
    width: inherit;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#blog-header .mid,
#blog-header .blog-logo {
    border-right: 2px solid #333333;
    float: left;
}

#blog-header .mid {
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 230px;
}

#blog-header .right {
    padding-left: 15px;
    float: right;
}

#blog-header .blog-logo {
    padding-right: 15px;
    width: 262px;
}

#blog-header .blurb {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #333333;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-family: Alexandria;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}

#blog-header .blog-social {
    clear: both;
    width: 125px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

#blog-header .blog-nav {
    padding: 7px 0 15px 0;
    width: 350px;
}

#blog-header .email {
    border-top: 2px solid #333333;
    padding-top: 17px;
    width: 350px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: you have too many unnecessary css codes. did you write them all by yourself or copy paste from somewhere?

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu By myself, but obviously could use some help.

Comment: @AliCarikcioglu I'm not asking you too. I've laid out what I was able to do on my own, which is probably 90% of what's needing to be done. I'm stuck as to what exactly needs to be done next to achieve my desired results. I don't see how the way I have formatted my question differs from the vast majority of questions on Stackoverflow? You can see from my question history that I am here to learn, not to leech.

Answer (score 1):

First, try not to style tags in your HTML with id tags. In fact, if at all possible, try not to style with classes either, unless you need to. You should Google CSS Selectors and try to use as many of those to style your HTML.

Since the only image you are using is the big none on the left, you don't need to put a span around it. Just float: left the image.

Also, are you using HTML5? If so, then #blog-header should instead be a  tag. If you have more than one header in your document, then you could give it a class to differentiate it if you needed to.

You also don't need a div around your unordered list of social icons. Just float the list, and display:inline the icons. And instead of using images as icons, you should Google Icon Fonts.

There's a lot more, but start there and get back to us once you've made those changes. Just remember, when it comes to HTML and CSS, less is more!

Comment: you hit the nail on the head, Mikes. great comment.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to tell me where I went wrong. This is all very much a learning process for me. I took what you said and revised the jsfiddle[http://jsfiddle.net/CUJhJ/8/]. Do you mind taking a look at it? Currently the social icons are distorted(which I think may have something to do with removing the span around the blog logo and styling the `img`..)

Also, I'm still stuck on how to get the grid-like spacing and height of the vertical borders. What have I missed? 

Thank you again.

Comment: Would love to assist, but I'm having trouble opening your link.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly post us the part where you are stuck at, not the whole css, what you exactly want, then we can help. It's pointless when you make %90 of whole project and ask us to re-write the project as a whole so we can fix your bugs.

By the way, the codes seem to be too long for such a banner. I removed half of your css and they worked exactly same. Either you took these from somewhere or you don't have any methodolody in learning curve.

I recommend you to take professional developing courses which might help you building clear codes.